Ballerina vs. Spring Boot Performance Discrepancy in Load Testing with JMeter
I'm currently conducting a research project comparing the performance of the Ballerina programming language with Spring Boot using JMeter for performance testing.
I've run several load tests on my system and found some intriguing results. Using a stepping thread group to increment the users and determine the maximum number of users each application can handle simultaneously, I observed the following:

Ballerina can handle only 15 users concurrently.
Spring Boot can handle approximately 6700 users concurrently.

These results are quite surprising, and I'm trying to understand why there is such a significant difference in performance between the two. Is this behavior typical? Are there any known limitations or configuration settings that might cause Ballerina to underperform in such scenarios?
For reference, you can find the detailed results of my performance tests in my GitHub repository here.
Environment Details:

Java version: GraalVM 22.0.1+8.1,

Ballerina version: 2201.8.0

System specifications: 32 RAM, 17-13700k CPU, Windows 11 Pro


Any insights, suggestions, or experiences with performance testing Ballerina and Spring Boot would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!
I have tried switching to several versions of Ballerina and changing my JMeter tests, expecting this difference to be insignificant.

You use concurrent in the above description, but in your repository you use the term simultaneous.  Please clarify.   True simultaneity is a rare condition where users are engaged in the same behavior at precisely the same time and faces the risk of hitting a critical section of code where a semaphore like lock takes place.

The above JMeter script uses a third-party plugin to create HTTP 2 requests. It creates new connections for each iteration and keeps them open for 20s. This creates a large amount of concurrent requests (around 7000) despite the UI showing 15 as the concurrency level.
Please use an HTTP 2 testing tool that can reuse HTTP connections.
I created an issue in the plugin's repo https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-http2-plugin/issues/72
